# What does SFM on a map mean?

Tags: meaning, acronyms

I am reading the book *A Voyage for Madman* by Peter Nichols. There are some maps on some pages. On those maps, I see the acronym "SFM" and have no idea what it means.

[image]

[image]

I looked SFM up on Google and I found lots of stuff about Source Film Maker, which is a software. I don't think this is what it means here...

I also looked on AcronymFinder and [I found lots of results](https://www.acronymfinder.com/SFM.html). None of them seems to fit the context.

What does this mean?

Comment: Given that all the other text on the maps orients with the map, but the *SFM* doesn't, it's likely some kind of meta symbol, in particularly the mapmaker's mark.

Comment: Yeah, sorta looks like the artist's initials.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center. It asks about someone's initials on a diagram.

Comment: @Edwin How is this not within the scope defined in the help centre? It shows research, it’s clear, and it’s about something which was very reasonably assumed to be some sort of specialised use of English. The fact that the _answer_ turned out to be unrelated to English does not make the _question_ off-topic.

Comment: @Janus   I consider reasonable research to include checking to see if these could be the initials of the illustrator. I ask _you_ how this question fits in with the mission statement of the site. Do we answer 'What do you think the acronym RAB stands for in this extract from a Harry Potter film?' next? / Note that the question has been put on hold.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That’s a completely different and incomparable scenario. RAB is very obviously initials in HP—it’s a signature in a letter. There is absolutely nothing to indicate that SFM should be initials in this case. It looks like part of the map, and initials are not normal parts of maps; it’s highly unusual, in fact, for map drawers to include their initials as part of book maps like this. The mission statement of the site is far too broad and wishy-washy a concept to be applied to individual questions. It applies to the **site**, not to whether a question is on-topic or not.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But yes, I do think this question fits with the mission statement of being a repository of authoritative answers to questions about the English language and its usage. It’s a question that many people reading the book will likely have and assume to be about English language usage, which makes it useful for future readers. Again, the _answer_ does not invalidate the _question_.

Comment: @Janus It's off-topic as a purely literary(/cartographic) usage / interpretation request, even if it wasn't recognised as one by OP.  Even were that not so, the number of people finding a general answer to such questions via the title 'What does SFM on a map mean?' will be zero to tiny.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I found the question and answer useful, I never knew that it was customary for an illustrator to write their initials, instead of their names on their works.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Names, pseudonyms, initials, monograms, identifying symbols / doodles. But still off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth  Only if the names, doodles, acronyms,  etc.  are general reference. Usually, a signature is recognizable as such. The letters SFM are in uppercase.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You can ask Andrew why he put the question on hold. I usually explain my judgements out of courtesy and a desire for avoidance of mediocrity, but I can see why others don't.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Janus Bahs Jacquet, myself and, possibly Centaurus are asking why is this question placed on hold? There is research, it is clear, useful  and the answer supplied clearly shows it is not a question of general reference.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth because you are the user whose name appears first in the banner, it seems reasonable to ask you.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A And I repeat: it concerns a literary / diagrammatic style choice (and quite possibly one rarely encountered nowadays). Such interpretation requests, whether or not OP recognises them as such, are off-topic.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, Edwin, This is a new kind of situation. I agree with Edwin that this could be off-topic (what the meaning of an acronym is seems to be a simple look up and judge) but the OP had done due diligence and is now looking for help. I don't think whether a question is off-topic should depend on the answer itself (which turns out to be non-English entirely (the illustrator's initials)) which could have _only_ been determined by having the book in ones hands, something no one here could have done. All said, I can't tell whether this is off-topic or even if we want it to be off topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's not a question about English. It's a question about cartography. Even if it's a question about a person's initials, that is common to many languages, which means it's not about English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The question was not about cartography, it was asking about the meaning of 3 letters. It looked like an acronym. We only knew it was the i)lustrator's initials after someone posted the answer.

Comment: @MariLou Not arguing in comments. If you can edit the question so it cannot be about cartography or art in general and is definitely about English, please do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first map shows SFM located somewhere notheast of Australia, around 20ºN. The second map, however, shows SFM at a different location, south of the African continent about 40º-50ºS. My conclusion is that SFM is not an acronym for a place on the map. It may be the mapmaker's initials.

Comment: You are right. I just went to the last page and saw that "All maps by Samuel F. Manning", never knew people put their initials at a place like that...

Comment: How does this match the requirements of ELU? It's worthy of a comment, and close-voting should follow.

Comment: @Sweeper -- Look at editorial cartoons in a newspaper.  The artist almost always has some sort of signature on the image.  This is common for many categories of hand drawings.